# How to upload laravel project on namecheap hosting

Tags: laravel-5, hosting, shared-hosting, namecheap

can somebody please tell me how to upload laravel project on namecheap shared hosting. I am using php version 7.2 and laravel version 5.7.

Comment: This is not really a question to ask on SO, please read more about [what topics you can ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Namecheap however have an article here which may help https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/181/27/how-do-i-upload-my-site

Comment: ok thanks @WaynePhipps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean how to deploy your project! Just Follow these steps :

1. Create a new folder: example **myfiles**.
2. Copy all your files to this folder.
3. Go to `myfiles -> public` and copy these files to **public_html** (or **your home folder - not myfiles**).
4. Open `index.php` and edit these lines : **24 & 38**

Like this :

```
require __DIR__.'/myfiles/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/myfiles/bootstrap/app.php';
```

5. Check your host [documentation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/181/27/how-do-i-upload-my-site) and upload your project.

> If you get an **ERROR HTTP 500** after deploying your project, just
>   upgrade PHP version to 7.2 and everything will work inchallah! ;)

Comment: Thanks @Saif Lahouiter. But i have fix the problem.

Comment: So, Please make it True ;) , An Answer for your problem :)